# Converting with ImageMagick - illegal parameter

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, imagemagick

I am trying to convert a PDF to JPG, main goal is to have a thumbnail so that the user can preview the PDF within the application.

Apparently ImageMagick is a good way to do this, yet so far I failed to get it to convert the file.

```
import subprocess

params = ['convert', '-density 300 -resize 220x205', 'dummy.pdf', 'thumb.jpg']
subprocess.check_call(params)
```

So this is what I am getting instead of having the file converted:

Unzulässiger Parameter - 300
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pdf_preview_test.py", line 4, in 
    subprocess.check_call(params)
  File "C:\Users\EliasMessner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 347, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['convert', '-density 300 -resize 220x205', 'dummy.pdf', 'thumb.jpg']' returned non-zero exit status 4.

I couldn't find any info about the problem. It looks like the "300" parameter is illegal but IMHO it is used correctly.. Help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are on Windows the code could be trying the built in Windows convert program. You do not say what version on Imagemagick you are using; V7 uses magick as opposed to convert which can prevent this problem.

If you allowed Imagemagick to add convert to the environmental path on install it would probably not be a problem - it never has for me on multiple installs.

You could try changing convert to the full path to convert surrounding the path in " ". You can rename the convert program e.g. myconvert and use that in the program rather than convert.

I would try a Imagemagick command out in the command line to prove it works as well first.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I already solved the problem by stating the path of the convert.exe, which is still not a perfect solution I think, because the script should also run on ther machines.

I checked which command is executed by entering "where convert" into the console and it told me both the IM and the windows native convert.exe files.

I am using IM v. 6.9